# Prevention of host header injection in ASP.NET?

Tags: http, asp.net, iis, host-header-injection

How can we mitigate host header injection in ASP.NET? I have already configured application binding in IIS and set static hostname but still, the vulnerability exists.

Comment: You might get some idea from this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869361/is-enableheaderchecking-true-enough-to-prevent-http-header-injection-attacks